# Split a list of files into multiple smaller lists based on file size in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am writing a method that will take a large list of files and split them into smaller lists that contain an equal total of disk space. Eg. a list with 1 file that is 100kb and another with 100 files that are 1kb each.

The code i have does the following. If all files in a list total to more than 500kb i want to split this list into smaller lists. This means if i have a total count of 600kb i will have 2 lists. I want to add 300kb (or as close as possible) worth of files to each of these lists.

I have code written that will do this fairly well, but there is a common type of scenario that will mess this up. If i have 99 files. 99 are 1kb each and the last file is 400kb. This code will go back and forth adding 1 file to each lists until both lists will have 49 files with 49kb in each of the lists, but now the final file which is huge will mean that 1 list will be 49kb and the other 449kb. I need a smart way to divide the files so that the 400kb file ends up in a list on its own.

```
int listcount = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalsize / listlimit); //500kb

    List<string>[] lists = new List<string>[listcount];
    double[] memorytotals = new double[listcount]; // this array will keep track of what the file size total is in each of the arrays.

    foreach(string file in filelist)
    {
        double size = new FileInfo(file).Length;

        int pos = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < memorytotals.Length; i++)
    {
        if (memorytotals[i] < memorytotals[pos]) { pos = i; }
    }
       if(size > memorytotals[pos])
        {
            //get the next smallest array that is not pos
            int pos2 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < memorytotals.Length; i++)
            {
                if (memorytotals[i] < memorytotals[pos2] && pos2 != pos) 
                { 
                    pos2 = i; 
                }
            }

            //if moving all contents of the smallest array into the second smallest array make for a smaller size than just putting the larger file directly into the smaller array than do it.
            double newlistTotal = memorytotals[pos] + memorytotals[pos2];
            if(newlistTotal < size)
            {
                lists[pos2].AddRange(lists[pos]);
                //empty the list in order to add the new larger file to this list.
                lists[pos].Clear();
            }
        }
        lists[pos].Add(file);
    }
```

Comment: You'll likely need to do a type of two-pass scenario: get the list of just the filenames and sizes, then break them down from there, before adding them to the split lists..

Comment: This sounds like a variation of a [packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems) - you may want to research generic packing algorithms

Comment: Maybe you can sort all the files, where the first ones are the heaviest. Then run your algorithm and I think it will work.

Comment: The problem is not simple,such as 400,200,290,47,63,the totalSize is smaller than 1000,but you mush use 3 list to hold them if your split size is 500

Comment: hmm the packing problem is exactly my issue so thanks a lot for that! Im starting to doubt if the processing required to achieve evenly sized lists will  outweigh the performance increase by having evenly sized lists to process through. I will look into this further and see if i can come up with a way to improve my current method without having huge amounts of additional processing

Comment: Wait; “outweigh the performance increase”?? Performance increase of what? You should tell us [your actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) and not what solution you have decided to use; you could be on the completely wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the optimal solution, but at least it split the files into different list with more less the same size. A lot of improvement can be done in the code, is just a first approach.

I order the files because of their sizes and then I start adding them to the list, checking that the limit is never overpassed.

```
int listcount = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalsize / listlimit); //500kb
            List<FileInfo> fileInfoList = new List<FileInfo>();

            List<string>[] lists = new List<string>[listcount];

            double[] memorytotals = new double[listcount]; // this array will keep track of what the file size total is in each of the arrays.

            foreach (string file in filelist)
            {
                fileInfoList.Add(new FileInfo(file));         // Add all the FileInfo to a list to order it                      
            }

            fileInfoList.OrderBy(r => r.Length);


            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfoList)
            {
                double size = fileInfo.Length;

                // flag for only add a file one time
                bool flag = true;


                for (int j = 0; j < memorytotals.Length; j++)
                {

                    // check if the file fits in the list
                    if (memorytotals[j] + size < listcount && flag)
                    {
                        memorytotals[j] = memorytotals[j] + size;
                        lists[j].Add(fileInfo.FullName);
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: This solution works well. I didnt want to waste huge amounts of processing to make the lists perfectly even so this fixes the issue that i had and wont take a lot of processing to complete

Answer (score 0):

I have written a method to pack the file,and I use int to replace `FileInfo`,it can test easier,of course,it is not a good implentment

```
static List<List<int>> SplitFileWithLimitSize(List<int> totalSizes, int limitSize)
{
    List<List<int>> resultList = new List<List<int>>();//the result packet
    List<int> tmp = new List<int>();
    int reduceSize = limitSize;
    while (true)
    {
        var maxSize = 0;
        var filters = totalSizes.Where(x => x <= reduceSize);//to fiter the possible size
        if (filters.Any())
        {
            maxSize = filters.Max();//get max size
        }
        if (maxSize == 0)
        {//there is no size got success ,so add the tmp to resultList,and reinit the parameters
            resultList.Add(tmp);
            tmp = new List<int>();
            reduceSize = limitSize;
            continue;
        }
        reduceSize = reduceSize - maxSize;
        totalSizes.Remove(maxSize);
        tmp.Add(maxSize);
        if (totalSizes.Count == 0)
        {//if there is nothing reduce in totalSizes,tmp to resultList,and  break the loop
            resultList.Add(tmp);
            break;
        }
    }
    //resultList.ForEach(x =>
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("Pack:" + string.Join(" ", x));
    //});
    return resultList;
}
```

The test method is

```
var totalSizes = new List<int>() { 400, 200, 290, 47, 63 };
var limitSize = 500;
SplitFileWithLimitSize(totalSizes, limitSize);//there will 3 packet in list
Console.WriteLine("#################");
totalSizes = new List<int>() { 400, 200, 290, 100, 10 };
SplitFileWithLimitSize(totalSizes, limitSize);//there will 2 packet in list
```

Comment: List<FileInfo> ?